# How MySQL handles select queries on non key attributes?

Tags: mysql, sql

How does SQL(MySql database management system) handles `SELECT * FROM table WHERE nonKeyAttribute = someValue`? Does it really scan whole table as searching is happening on non-key column?

Edit:
Consider, No index is present on the search attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might.

It also might:

- Return the results from a cache if the same query was just called.
- Scan only the partition that has `nonKeyAttribute`, if the column is used for partitioning.
- Lookup matching rows in an index on `nonKeyAttribute` if it is the first column in an index (some databases relax that condition).

Comment: I got what do you want to say by 1st and 3rd point. 
What is partitioning in MySQL? 
I am familiar with it in DynamoDB(NoSQL) but that too happened on PrimaryKey.

Comment: @KuldeepYadav . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html.